# Next js : router.push routes to the target url but reloads it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, router

I have a page structure like

```
pages
     [re]
       login
          [slug.tsx]
```

From one of the rendered pages, `http://localhost:3000/in/login/data1` on button click `router.push` is called,

```
router.push(`in/login/data2`, undefined, { locale });
```

As expected `router.push` routes to the target path with the updated view BUT it reloads the page clearing the redux store.
Any pointer to why this is happening ?

**Note :** The issue happens if I directly load `http://localhost:3000/in/login/data1` in browser and on click on button to go to `http://localhost:3000/in/login/data2`. But all works fine if go to `http://localhost:3000/in/login/data1` from the home page `http://localhost:3000/` by clicking on

```
<Link href="/in/login/data1">
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something called shallow routing. Shallow routing allows you to change route without page refresh. All you need to do is pass shallow true in your router.push function like this

`` router.push(`in/login/data2`, undefined, { shallow: true }); ``

Comment: it doesn't work in my case. I'm not looking to change simply the route but the component view also. But I don't want a page reload

Comment: well that's what shallow routing is for. Can I get access to your code to take a closer look at the problem?